# Kubectl deployment - how to load env vars from JSON file

Tags: asp.net, json, kubernetes, environment-variables, kubectl

I'm using kubectl to deploy ASP.Net core apps to K8S cluster.
At the current moment I hardcode container PORTs and ConnectionString for DataBase like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mydeploy
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mydeploy
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mydeploy
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mydeploy
          image: harbor.com/my_app:latest
          env:
          - name: MyApp__ConnectionString
            value: "Host=postgres-ap-svc;Port=5432;Database=db;Username=postgres;Password=password"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5076
```

But the good solution I think - to use such variables from `appsettings.json` file (ASP.Net config file).
**So my question - How to load this vars from JSON file and use in yaml file?**

JSON file is like this:

```
{
  "MyApp": {
    "ConnectionString": "Host=postgres-ap-svc;Port=5432;Database=db;Username=postgres;Password=password"
  },
  "ClientBaseUrls": {
    "MyApp": "http://mydeploy-svc:5076/api",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use following command to create configmap and then mount it to your contianer

```
kubectl create configmap appsettings --from-file=appsettings.json --dry-run -o yaml
```

For mounting you should add a volume to your deployment or sts like this:

```
  volumes:
    - name: config
      configMap:
        name: appsettings
```

And then mount it to your container:

```
 volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /appropriate/path/to/config/appsettings.json
          subPath: appsettings.json
          name: config
```

Also if you want you can use the config map as your environment variables source like this:

```
envFrom:
      - configMapRef:
          name: config
```

Comment: thank you for response! I tried your solution - looks like it just create one env var that contains all json file. I can't understand how to use it. If I run `printenv` in container I see `appsettings.json={
  "MyApp": {
    "ConnectionString": "Host=postgres-ap-svc;Port=5432;Database=db;Username=postgres;Password=password"
  },
  "ClientBaseUrls": {
    "MyApp": "http://mydeploy-svc:5076/api",
  }
}`

while I want something like:
`"MyApp__ConnectionString":"..."` and `"ClientBaseUrls__MyApp":"..."`

Comment: You should create the configmap using --from-env-file option instead. For example: `kubectl create configmap appsettings --from-env-file=appsettings.json --dry-run -o yaml` And use envFrom like mentioned in the post kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/…

Comment: looks like `--from-env-file` option doesn't work with `json`: `error: "{" is not a valid key name`... :(

Comment: Sorry, the only workaround I know is either to manually convert json to key vlaues or to convert json to properties file using tools like jq

Answer (score 1):

You can try using literal mode:

```
kubectl create configmap appsettings --from-literal='ConnectionString'='Host=postgres-ap-svc;Port=5432;Database=db;Username=postgres;Password=password' --from-literal='MyApp'='http://mydeploy-svc:5076/api'
```

If this doesn't work you may need to write separate JSON-YAML parser.

Answer (score -1):

I'm putting all the comments as a community wiki answer for better usability.

If you run `printenv` in a container and see:

`appsettings.json={   "MyApp": {     "ConnectionString": "Host=postgres-ap-svc;Port=5432;Database=db;Username=postgres;Password=password"   },   "ClientBaseUrls": {     "MyApp": "http://mydeploy-svc:5076/api",   } }`

instead of something like: `"MyApp__ConnectionString":"..."` and `"ClientBaseUrls__MyApp":"..."`

you should create the configmap using `--from-env-file` option instead.

For example: `kubectl create configmap appsettings --from-env-file=appsettings.json --dry-run -o yaml` And use `envFrom` like mentioned in the post [kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#define-the-key-to-use-when-creating-a-configmap-from-a-file).

Comment: Hi! Thank you for response, but this is not the answer. `kubectl create ConfigMap --from-env-file` works on yaml only and cannot be used for JSON file. So this doesn't work